# Migrating Chatter content to new user

Tags: api, chatter, migration

When a user has a certain profile/license, Salesforce is quite strict about what alternative profiles/licenses you can move the user to. For example you cannot change an external 'Customer Community' user so that they have an internal 'Salesforce Platform' license and profile.

So in those circumstances it seems you have to rename the old user to '.old' and create a new user with the new profile/license.

But then all their old chatter history, group memberships etc are no longer connected to the new user.

In theory it seems it is possible to copy all the chatter posts, follows, group memberships from the old user to the new user, via the Chatter API.

My question is: has anyone tried this, or are there any existing apps/utilities/code examples that do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a serious limitation of Communities at present and it's also one of the reasons why Salesforce 1 currently isn't available for use in Communities. I'm not aware of a solution, but I do know that SF is working on a solution that will allow users to belong to more than one Community as part of support for enabling Salesforce 1 in Communities. During Salesforce 1 Developer Week (Safe Harbor here), I believe we were told to expect Summer 14 or Winter 14 release.

Hopefully someone else will have an answer regarding using the Chatter API to reassign or clone posts to the new user name.

Comment: Salesforce1 is available for Communities through the browser (/one/one.app)

Comment: You're not referring to native Visual Force pages that have been enabled for SF1 with cards are you? If so, I believe you're mistaken. Only custom SF1 apps are available at the moment for use in Communities.

Comment: I'm talking about the S1 UI. Log into your community on a browser and append /one/one.app to the base URL of your community and you have the Salesforce1 version of that community in your browser.

Comment: I believe support for that on a mobile device is still in beta, at least that's what we were told a few weeks ago. If it doesn't work in a mobile device, having it work in a regular browser seems rather pointless to me.

Comment: Salesforce1 in the native iOS and Android apps is not yet available for Communities, but support for Communities through the browser, either mobile browser or desktop, in Salesforce1 is available as of the Spring '14 release. See the release notes.

Comment: Guess it comes down to a matter of semantics. Safe to say that SF1 is HTML5, but not deliverable as an "iOS or Android app" in the same context that it's available on the rest of the platform. Fair enough?

Comment: I think there are uses for the browser version of S1 and uses for the native apps. If you wanted your own hybrid app, app icon and full branding control for example, you'd need to wrap Salesforce1 in the browser using the mobile SDK.